# How to make two threads in C# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am new to C#.I am working with WPF. I have small knowledge about Threading in Win32Console Application and made a program that ran two loops in parallel.The problem occurs when making a wpf application.How will I be able to make two threads, one thread should run the UI and the other thread should update the `UI` `textbox`.

Comment: You can't. Updating the textbox is updating the UI and that can only be done by the UI thread. Have the second thread ask the UI thread to change the textbox.

Comment: The `Dispatcher` in WPF is used to run code on your main UI thread, often at different priority levels. Typically you'd run your background thread using whatever multithreading style you want (TPL is my preference), then use the Dispatcher to send a UI update back to the main thread. Do some searches on the `Dispatcher` to see some examples :)

Comment: The most current, most flexible idiom in WPF and C# now is `async`/`await`, which you can use with `Task` and other asynchronous implementations to run operations outside the UI thread and then transfer control automatically back to the UI thread as needed (e.g. to make changes to data that are bound to UI). But your question as stated is far too broad. Research these techniques, make some attempts, and post a clear, _specific_ question if you run into problems.

Comment: Rachel , I used Dispatcher but why cant I just simply make two threads for example I want to show a "Loading..." window but when the window opens it shows the window but text is not shown.I want to make a thread that show  "Loading..." and an other thread that show the window

Comment: @user36734 That is because objects can only be modified *from the thread they were created*. If you create a UI object on the UI thread, it can only be modified from the UI thread. Typically you create all objects on the UI thread, do any long processes on a background thread, then pass the result back to the main thread once finished so it can update the UI objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution.... using TPL and sending an event.  Note that this method has zero knowledge of who is wanting the data and doesn't care who called it.

```
public void doAsync(){
   var list = new List<ofSomething>();
   Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
        //You are now in a new thread, just do your stuff here.
        var somerange = GetSomeRange();
        list.AddRange(somerange);
   }).Continue((p)=>{
       //you are now on GUI thread send event or return the list.
       //I personally like to send events.
       if(PostDataReady != null) PostDataReady(list);
   });

}
```

Comment: The purpose of the TPL is to provide a paradigm for asynchronous programming that's far more effective than an event based model.  If you're going to use events, there's not really any reason to use tasks, and if you're using tasks, you lose most of the benefits by using events in this manor.

Comment: Oh no not Servy downvoting me again!  I guess I just shouldn't contribute at all to these forums because Servy doesn't like anything I post.  Here's a correction to you Servy:  The Task class support was published  *before*  Async/Await, it's actually very easy to use and preferred by many.  You are also incorrect on events precluding tasks.  If the caller of the GUI thread's GetSomeRange method blocks so will the GUI, the event handler is just a nice way to notify more than one listener.  I didn't say this was the definitive answer, it's just one possible solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote your post, but since you seem to want me to, I've obliged you.  Notice I didn't so much as mention async/await.  I'm well aware that one can use Tasks without it.  A well designed TPL implementation of this behavior would simply mean *returning the task* instead of firing an event to which `async/await` need not be involved.

Comment: If you're into RX then firing the event is almost the equivalent, upon a thread's return,  I mean what else is easier than calling a method and forgetting about it?

Comment: @user36734 Just ignore the on-hold status and try the possible answer I gave you I think you'll find it works well for you.

Comment: Rx (just like the TPL and other platforms for asynchronous programming) does have things in common with events, but that too adds quite a bit of enhanced functionality on top of an event based model of programming, particularly for operations like this.  An event based model means attaching an event handler, firing the event, handling the event separately, removing the event handler, having some way of being notified of cancellation/errors, etc. The TPL was explicitly designed to make asynchronous programming easier. You're going ou tof your way to inhibit use of of that added functionality.

Comment: Perhaps but it goes back a long way, prior to Tasks and the realization that event based programming model was a superior model to just pull based models.  When the EventHandler model was introduced, it made event wiring simple.  So in essence before RX was in existence this model above was doing the functional equivalent. It's a hold over from what was before Tasks, and even RX, and it works well.  Agreed I do need to bone up on newer methods.

Comment: Of course the event based model is older.  It goes back to C# 1.0 (as does a callback-based model), whereas tasks only go back to C# 4.0.  That doesn't make events *better*.  The fact that `Task` was added specifically because trying to program complex programs using an event based (or callback based) model was too hard for most programmers, and the `Task` based model was created to replace it, should tell you something.  And again, if you *really* want to use the event based model, then *why are you using tasks in the first place*.  If you want to write a C# 1.0 program then do that.

Comment: Okay thanks for the input Servy, I just ordered some books on Amazon on the matter!